# Steiner tree sub-optimal algorithm always finds the optimal solution. Why?

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, spanning-trees

I am using the algorithm implemented by the library `networkx` to solve a Steiner minimal tree problem.

They claim their algorithm to give an approximated solution.

However, I am working on a specific group of graphs, namely, grid lattices (with capacity 1).

I believe this group of circuit belongs the Euclidean group, which should be hard to solve as well(?).

On my experiments I keep getting the optimal solutions, so I wonder what property my graph has to guarantee that. Is it because of the capacity? Or maybe because it is a grid?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP-hard in general. I suspect that your problems are rather small or have few terminals and are therefore easy to solve, even for an approximation algorithm.